# Jquery IE external custom function is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, function, undefined

I have a function called `flyout`, which slides a menu div in on a button click and out on click again.

**Problem 1:** It runs fine in Chrome, FF etc but IE9 tells me that `flyout is undefined`, though the function still works.

**Problem 2:** In IE8 no error message but the menu slides in and back out on one click.

I'm not sure but am hoping that both problems are related. I'm fairly new to Jquery and Jquery UI so am not sure if I am using everything correctly. Any help would be very appreciated.

JS in external javascript file:

```
$(function flyout() {
    $(".btn-toggle").click(function (e) {
        var newSelector = $('#flyout-' + $(this).attr('id')),
            toggle = newSelector.css('display') == 'block';

        e.preventDefault();
        newSelector.toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
        $('.hide').not(newSelector).hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);

        if (!toggle) {
            newSelector.children('.l-menu').effect('highlight', 1000);
            $('a.btn-toggle i').removeClass('icon-chevron-right');
            $(this).find('.icon-chevron-left').toggleClass('icon-chevron-right');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.icon-chevron-left').toggleClass('icon-chevron-right');
        };
    });
});
```

HTML and JS:

```
<a href="#" id="fo2" class="btn btn-small btn-info btn-toggle"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> Helpful Hints</a>
<a href="#" id="fo1" class="btn btn-small btn-amber btn-toggle"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> <i class="icon-tasks"></i> Progress</a>

<div id="flyout-fo2" class="fixed-tr hide">
    ...Menu HTML
</div>
<div id="flyout-fo1" class="fixed-tr2 hide">
    ...Menu HTML
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        flyout();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There might be some specification against naming anonymous functions.

Comment: This is not an anonymous function, he is making a jQuery object of the function.

Comment: @Niels `$(function)` is a shortcut for `(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a jQuery object of a function. Why?

Change external file to this:

```
function flyout() {
    $(".btn-toggle").click(function (e) {
        var newSelector = $('#flyout-' + $(this).attr('id')),
            toggle = newSelector.css('display') == 'block';

        e.preventDefault();
        newSelector.toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
        $('.hide').not(newSelector).hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);

        if (!toggle) {
            newSelector.children('.l-menu').effect('highlight', 1000);
            $('a.btn-toggle i').removeClass('icon-chevron-right');
            $(this).find('.icon-chevron-left').toggleClass('icon-chevron-right');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.icon-chevron-left').toggleClass('icon-chevron-right');
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Niels! I'm basically doing it this way because I need it to be used on about 30 pages. I wrote it inline first  and then moved it to an external file. Is there a better/correct way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks also @Brad M. What you wrote helped me understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially adding two event handlers to the DOM ready callback.

The first

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    flyout();
});
```

And then secondly

```
$(function flyout() {
```

`$(function)` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

The solution is to just declare the `function flyout(){}` separately.
Then do

```
$(flyout);
```